# Swift - UIButton setting constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, constraints

I am having problems with setting my `height` and `width` `constraints` for my `UIButton`. I have no idea why this code is not working:

```
let wishButton: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton()
    v.setImage(UIImage(named: "wishButton"), for: .normal)
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(wishButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return v
}()
```

These are my constraints:

```
wishButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popUpView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
wishButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popUpView.centerYAnchor, constant: 150).isActive = true
wishButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
wishButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

This is how it looks at the moment:

[image]

It's weird because the other two `constraints` are working just fine. Probably just a stupid mistake but I am quite new and grateful for every help :)

Comment: can you share the screenshot of how your button is currently looking? also, set v.clipsToBounds=true

Comment: @KeshuRai just edited my question :)

Comment: Is the button the black square where the whole of it is the `wishButton` image, or is that a view with the button inside it?  It'd alsohelp if you could show the code of how you are adding the constraints / presenting the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constraints have no issues. The issue is with the image. Your image is not big enough to fill the frame. You can set the `.setBackgroundImage` of the button to make it automatically scalable.

```
v.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "wishButton"), for: .normal)
```

or you can make the *content Alignment* equal to `.fill` on both directions.

Comment: you're right that was the problem :) @Ashmet Bhui just said it as well, thanks to you both !

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is it doesn't look like you have set the **frame** of the button.

Try adding this line after you initialize the button:

```
v.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
```

I'm not sure if it is required but if your button isn't showing up at all, this may fix the issue

Comment: I see you have posted a picture...which object is the button that doesn't look correct? and what is the desired look?

Comment: the circle at the bottom. I just want to change it's size

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your UIButton initialisation, it will work

```
v.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
v.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
```

It will scale your image.

```
let wishButton: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton()
    v.setImage(UIImage(named: "wishButton"), for: .normal)
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
    v.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
    v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(wishButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return v
}()
```

Comment: that was it :) Thanks you very much!